# how to send login information to server through socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, authentication, messenger

I'm trying to write an `instant messenger` , which has a `client application` and a `server application` which should run separately on each client computer and server .
of course the clients are communicating with each other through a `socket` .
and I'm saving each client's information on the server . which means that the client's application should send the login information to the server and Waite to hear the result .
i want to know  what is the best way to send the information to server ? should i send it through the same `socket` or what ?

Comment: Yeah you need to open an `InputStream` and `OutputStream` to write the bytes to server to client. For login type applications i like using `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` thats just me though...

Comment: Use InputStream and Outputstream from the Socket to write over through.

Comment: well . im gonna use the same i/o streams for chat . would'nt this make any trouble ?

Comment: You can make a different server and only send login requests to it and send back if it is okay or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket programming is an interesting topic in java. It can use two main methodologies to program an instant messenger.

**I assume that you know how to programme sockets and working with it's data streams. I only provide the logic of instant messenger with login.**

**1. Server-Client method**

It requires two different progammes such client application and server application. Server side user login can only be performed using this method. It's possible to transmit data which is encoded by json or xml. Received data decodes into the object. Then it's possible to identify the data is a message or login information to the server. Consider following example.

- Create a Data Object to transmit

class TransmitData {

```
    private String userName;//user name of sender
    private String password;//password of the sender
    private String toUser;//user name of receiver
    private String type;//message type which is a message or login information
    //message types
    public static final String MESSAGE = "MESSAGE";
    public static final String LOGIN_INFORMATION = "LOGIN_INFORMATION";

    public TransmitData() {
    }

    //add getters and setters here

}
```

- Then convert into xml or json String

  `<transmit-data>
      <user-name></user-name>
      <password></password>
      <to-user></to-user>
      <message-type></message-type>
  </transmit-data>`
- After that send xml data via socket connection
- Decode message at the server
- Identify message type and perform next actions

However server-client instant messengers are not usable when server is offline. So it is not recommended when use in a local area network.

**2. Peer-to-Peer method**

Peer-to-Peer instance messegers has only one programme which containing both server and client coding. It's hard develop and out of logic when using server-side user login. But you can add client side login to the messenger easily. It's possible to add features to search and add other users to a address book. Then I will become smarter when using. As an advantage it does not require a server. I think it's very good when you use instant messenger in local area network.